# XSLT transformation from XML to XML

Tags: xslt

I am trying to update all `<type>` values to lower case which is working fine now. Also i wanted to change the namespace from v2.0 to v1.0 and it worked fine except that i don't want namespace to be declared for subelements like "category" and "authList" below. and most important thing i wanted to do is replace `<Name>` element with `<Number>` along with new numeric value to it. 
So 2 outstanding things i am trying to acheive here are:
1. Update the 'Name' element to 'Number' with new numeric value. (MUST for me)
2. If possible remove Namespaces from 'Category' or other subelements in the document except for the root element.  (IF POSSIBLE)

Please let me know what is wrong with my XSLT. Thanks a lot. I hope i was able to keep the question simple.

XML Input:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <ns6:QueryResponse version="2.0" xmlns="" xmlns:ns6="http://www.abc.com/s/v2.0">
     <category>
        <categoryList>
           <cat>
              <type>SUPER</type>
              <value>gg44</value>
           </cat>
           <cat>
              <type>SUPER2</type>
              <value>fff</value>
           </cat>
        </categoryList>
     </category>
     <AuthList>
        <sAuthority>
           <Name>P</Name>
    </sAuthority>               
<AuthList>               
 </ns6:QueryResponse>
 </soapenv:Body>
 </soapenv:Envelope>
```

XML output -

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <v1:QueryResponse version="1.0" xmlns:v1="http://www.abc.com/s/v1.0">
     <category xmlns:ns2="http://www.abc.com/s/v1.0" xmlns:ns3="http://www.abc.com/s/v2.0">
        <categoryList>
           <cat>
              <type>super</type>
              <value>gg44</value>
           </cat>
           <cat>
              <type>super2</type>
              <value>fff</value>
           </cat>
        </categoryList>
     </category>
     <AuthList xmlns:ns2="http://www.abc.com/s/v1.0"  xmlns:ns3="http://www.abc.com/s/v2.0">
        <sAuthority>
           <Name>P</Name>
    </sAuthority>               
<AuthList>               
 </v1:QueryResponse>
 </soapenv:Body>
 </soapenv:Envelope>
```

XSLT code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:old="http://www.abc.com/s/v2.0"
exclude-result-prefixes="old"
xmlns:v1="http://www.abc.com/s/v1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"
   version="1.0" />

<!-- Some parameters declered -->
<xsl:param name="newversion" select="'1.0'" />   
<xsl:param name="P_1" select="'1'" />
<xsl:param name="C_2" select="'2'" />
<xsl:param name="S_3" select="'3'" />
<xsl:param name="F_4" select="'4'" />   

<!-- This is to update namespace from v2.0 to v1.0 -->
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="old:*">
    <xsl:element name="v1:{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="old:QueryResponse/@version">
    <xsl:attribute name="version"> 
    <xsl:value-of select="$newversion" /> 
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<!-- This is to update the Name to Number -->
<xsl:template match="sAuthority/Name">
  <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test=".='P'">
       <xsl:element name="Number">
       <xsl:value-of select="$P_1"/>           
       </xsl:element>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:when test=".='C'">
       <xsl:element name="Number">
       <xsl:value-of select="$C_2"/>
       </xsl:element>                      
   </xsl:when>       
   <xsl:when test=".='S'">
       <xsl:element name="Number">
       <xsl:value-of select="$S_3"/>
       </xsl:element>          
   </xsl:when>  
   <xsl:when test=".='F'">
       <xsl:element name="Number">
       <xsl:value-of select="$F_4"/>
       </xsl:element>      
   </xsl:when>                   
  </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>  

 <!-- This is to update Upper case values to lower case for all the type elements in  the XML input whereever they are in the XML -->
 <xsl:template match="type/text()">
   <xsl:value-of
       select="translate (., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')" />
  </xsl:template>

  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

EXpected Output:-

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <v1:QueryResponse version="1.0" xmlns:v1="http://www.abc.com/s/v1.0">
     <category>
        <categoryList>
           <cat>
              <type>super</type>
              <value>gg44</value>
           </cat>
           <cat>
              <type>super2</type>
              <value>fff</value>
           </cat>
        </categoryList>
     </category>
     <AuthList>
        <sAuthority>
           <Number>1</Number>
    </sAuthority>               
<AuthList>               
 </v1:QueryResponse>
 </soapenv:Body>
 </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Thanks,

Comment: You say you want to convert your values to lowercase, but your expected output has values in uppercase. You say you want to remove the namespaces from (I can only assume) everything inside `QueryResponse`, but your input already has no namespaces on everything inside `QueryResponse`. There seem to be a lot of inconsistencies here.

Comment: Apologies, I just updated the post. Kindly let me know if i am making sense here...and suggest a workaround. Also yes my input XML doesn't have namespace for subelements its only on the root element QueryResponse.

Comment: What is the significance of the XML Output (your second code snippet) in this situation? Is that the output you are currently getting? It looks like your input still doesn't have namespaces on anything inside `QueryResponse`. Did you accidentally delete them?

Comment: Yes the XML output is what i am getting after i applied the XSLT code shared above. and i do not have namespaces anywhere in the actual input file as well except on the root element. The orginal file was too large and i have just reduced the data elements to post the question.

Comment: I don't see any namespace associated with any child element of QueryResponse. Are we missing something? So, what are you trying to do with the namespace? If it is not there, then how will you remove it? ;)
Also, in the XSLT, just check the xpath for the element Number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to remove namespace declarations from the **category** and **authlist** elements, try adding this additional template to your XSLT

```
<xsl:template match="*[namespace-uri()='']">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

This works because **xsl:copy** will copy across any namespace declarations from your input XML (whether they are used or not), so instead rather than copying the elements you create new elements, which won't have the declarations.

As from changing **Name** into **Number**, your XSLT looks like it is doing this correctly already. However, I would suggest that instead of using **xsl:choose**, you consider writing a series of templates, like so:

```
<xsl:template match="sAuthority/Name">
  <number>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </number>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Name/text()[.='P']">
  <xsl:value-of select="$P_1"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Name/text()[.='C']">
  <xsl:value-of select="$C_2"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Name/text()[.='S']">
  <xsl:value-of select="$S_3"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Name/text()[.='F']">
  <xsl:value-of select="$F_4"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Let me give this a try and see how it goes. Aprreciate it.

Comment: Ok your code for namespace worked, The namespaces on child elements were removed as expected great.... one question regarding your suggestion for Name to Number conversion...any advantages or disadvatages using template versus xsl:choose. just to remind that along with changing the value i also need to change the name of the element i.e from Name to Number? Thanks very much.